# How to use " null "data in "react-native-datepicker" ? I want to use null data if user want

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a mobile app for iOS and Android.
Now I want to make user use null data or date but I don't mean that I want to use PlaceHolder.

I mean user can select "null" or specific date like "11-30-2018".

**Using component :**

react-native-datepicker
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

Could someone please teach me that.

Comment: let the user choose 'null' (with a button or whatever element) OR the date with the datepicker widget - eg. don't show the datepicker at all if the user doesn't want to pick up a date

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes actually I wanna use a button or an element to make user choose "null" but I dont know how to do that....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `disable` property of the datepicker, to have it disabled in that case, which seems to best reflect the "null" value in your situation in my opinion. You can have a button that the user can use to choose the "null" value and have it change a variable in the state, which is responsible for disabling the datepicker.

`<DatePicker disabled = this.state.disabled ...`

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with creating other button like "clear button".

I read a description of this component and tried some ways for my purpose but I couldn't. 
So, I decided to create other button which can make inputted date clear.

Thank you for your all helping.